# How to detect a value change of a Datepicker using SwiftUI and Combine?

Tags: events, datepicker, swiftui, combine, valuechangelistener

How would you detect a change of value of a Datepicker while using SwiftUI and Combine?
I need to invoke a method whenever the datepicker wheel is moved, to update a Text and a Slider.

I have looked for specific methods to identify the value change (using UIKit it was possible to associate an action to an event), but apparently I haven't found anything useful in the documentation (I've tried the onTapGesture methods, but that's not what I want, since it forces the user to tap the picker to update the other views, whereas I would like to have an automatic update whenever the user moves the wheel).

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    private var calendar = Calendar.current

    @State private var date = Date()
    @State private var weekOfYear = Double(Calendar.current.component(.weekOfYear, from: Date()) )
    @State private var lastWeekOfThisYear = 53.0
    @State private var weekDay: String = { () -> String in 
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        let weekDay = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        return weekDay
    }()

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            // Date Picker
            DatePicker(selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date, label:{ Text("Please enter a date") }
            )
            .labelsHidden()
            .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
            .onTapGesture {
                self.updateWeekAndDayFromDate()
            }

            // Week number and day
            Text("Week \(Int(weekOfYear.rounded()))")
            Text("\(weekDay)")

            // Slider
            Slider(value: $weekOfYear, in: 1...lastWeekOfThisYear, onEditingChanged: { _ in
                    self.updateDateFromWeek()
                })
            }

    }

    func updateWeekAndDayFromDate() {
        // To do
    }

    func updateDateFromWeek() {
        // To do
    }

    func setToday() {
        // To do
    }

    func getWeekDay(_ date: Date) -> String {
        //To do
    }
}
```

I guess this could be solved using Combine (observableobject, published, sink, etc.), but I'm not experienced yet with Combine, therefore I'd like to ask for some help... any ideas? :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This can all be done using bindings and states. Could you share your code for the slider and text as well, please?

Comment: Sure, I have added some more code in my post. What I'm doing is using the datepicker wheel to select a date, and update a label showing the year week (from 1 to 53) and the position of the slider (also representing the year week). At the same time, when I move the slider I want to update the status of the picker (this last part I can already do, since I use on the slider 'onEditingChanged' to call my update method, even if this update the picker only when I terminate the movement of the slider, whereas I would prefer a continuous update). I couldn't do the opposite (update the slider/laber).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please find below one possible approach (with a bit modified your code). Here is an idea to have source state transparent to activate dependent within it. Hope it will be helpful somehow.

Here is demo

[image: dependent binding of DatePicker]

Here is code

```
struct TestDatePicker: View {

    private static func weekOfYear(for date: Date) -> Double {
        Double(Calendar.current.component(.weekOfYear, from: date))
    }

    private static func weekDay(for date: Date) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        let weekDay = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        return weekDay
    }

    @State private var date: Date
    @State private var weekOfYear: Double
    @State private var weekDay: String
    @State private var lastWeekOfThisYear = 53.0

    private var dateProxy:Binding<Date> {
        Binding<Date>(get: {self.date }, set: {
            self.date = $0
            self.updateWeekAndDayFromDate()
        })
    }

    init() {
        let now = Date()
        self._date = State<Date>(initialValue: now)
        self._weekOfYear = State<Double>(initialValue: Self.weekOfYear(for: now))
        self._weekDay = State<String>(initialValue: Self.weekDay(for: now))
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            // Date Picker
            DatePicker(selection: dateProxy, displayedComponents: .date, label:{ Text("Please enter a date") }
            )
            .labelsHidden()
            .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())

            // Week number and day
            Text("Week \(Int(weekOfYear.rounded()))")
            Text("\(weekDay)")

            // Slider
            Slider(value: $weekOfYear, in: 1...lastWeekOfThisYear, onEditingChanged: { _ in
                    self.updateDateFromWeek()
                })
            }

    }

    func updateWeekAndDayFromDate() {
        self.weekOfYear = Self.weekOfYear(for: self.date)
        self.weekDay = Self.weekDay(for: self.date)
    }

    func updateDateFromWeek() {
        // To do
    }

    func setToday() {
        // To do
    }

    func getWeekDay(_ date: Date) -> String {
        ""
    }
}

struct TestDatePicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestDatePicker()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

An easier way is using .onChange on DatePicker:

```
DatePicker(
    "Datum",
    selection: $date,
    displayedComponents: [.date]
).onChange(of: date, perform: { value in
     // Do what you want with "date", like array.timeStamp = date
});
```

Comment: This is good, however only available in iOS14+, if you need this for iOS13 have a look at the last example in [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-run-some-code-when-state-changes-using-onchange).

Comment: Also I've found that if you change the month/date from the larger DatePicker view it considers that a selection as well so I'm looking for a way to only close the view if they pick a date inside the month view.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work if you select the same date that's already selected

Comment: this doesn't work on `macOS`

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach using ObservableObject

```
class TestPikerModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var expireDate: Date = Date()
}

struct TestPikerView: View {

    @ObservedObject var testPikerModel = TestPikerModel()
    @State private var weekOfYear = Double(Calendar.current.component(.weekOfYear, from: Date()) )

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            Text("\(Int(weekOfYear))")
            DatePicker("", selection: $testPikerModel.expireDate, displayedComponents: .date)
            .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
            .clipped()
            .labelsHidden()
        }
        .onReceive(testPikerModel.$expireDate) { date in
            weekOfYear = Double(Calendar.current.component(.weekOfYear, from: date))
            updateWeekAndDayFromDate()
        }
    }

    func updateWeekAndDayFromDate() {
        print("updateWeekAndDayFromDate performed")
    }
}

struct TestPikerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestPikerView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be, where observer in viewModel is called whenever date is changed

```
class TestPikerModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var expireDate: Date = Date()

init() {
       setupObserver()
    }
    
private func setupObserver() {
        $expireDate
            .sink { date in
                // do some networking call
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

struct TestPikerView: View {

    @ObservedObject var testPikerModel = TestPikerModel()
    @State private var weekOfYear = Double(Calendar.current.component(.weekOfYear, from: Date()) )

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            Text("\(Int(weekOfYear))")
            DatePicker("", selection: $testPikerModel.expireDate, displayedComponents: .date)
            .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
            .clipped()
            .labelsHidden()
        }

    }

}
```