# How to set the style of the textField part of a DatePicker

Tags: swiftui

I used a DatePicker inside a Form, and It looks like the following image ,
Now,I hope it display "2020-4-19 " instead of "4/19/20 ".
Someone knows how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the code here rather than having a picture of the code.

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051670/change-selected-date-format-from-datepicker-swiftui

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a way with the default DatePicker, so I've taken the code from 
 [Change selected date format from DatePicker SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051670/change-selected-date-format-from-datepicker-swiftui/59166390#59166390)

made some changes to make it work. This CustomDatePicker should do you what you asked for even within a Form.

```
struct CustomDatePicker: View {
@State var text: String = "Date"
@Binding var date: Date
@State var formatString: String = "yyyy-MM-dd"

@State private var disble: Bool = false
@State private var showPicker: Bool = false
@State private var selectedDateText: String = "Date"

let formatter = DateFormatter()

private func setDateString() {
    formatter.dateFormat = formatString
    self.selectedDateText = formatter.string(from: self.date)
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Text(text).frame(alignment: .leading)
            Spacer()
            Text(self.selectedDateText)
                .onAppear() {
                    self.setDateString()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showPicker.toggle()
            }.multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        }

        if showPicker {
            DatePicker("", selection: Binding<Date>(
                get: { self.date},
                set : {
                    self.date = $0
                    self.setDateString()
            }), displayedComponents: .date)
                .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
                .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
}

struct ContentView: View {

@State var date = Date()

var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section {
            CustomDatePicker(text: "my date", date: $date, formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd")
        Text("test")
    }
}
}
```