# Overlaying date picker over list section

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a scenario where I need to show date picker and selected date in different format. Since SwiftUI's date picker shows date in a specific format after it's selected, I thought of opening date picker on a button click instead of directly using SwiftUI date picker, so I can display the date in desired format as button title. However, the date picker doesn't open over the list section within which the button resides.

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    showSheet = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Click Me").foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                SampleSheet()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SampleSheet: View {
    @State private var selectedDate = Date.now
    @State private var selectedPicker = "Day"
    @State private var dateLabelTitle = "Date"
    @State private var displayDate = "Mar 7, 2024"
    
    @State private var showDatePicker: Bool = false
    let segments = ["Day", "Week", "Month"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                filterDateSection
                dateRangeSelectionSection
            }
            .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
            .overlay {
                if showDatePicker {
                    DatePicker(
                        "",
                        selection: $selectedDate,
                        displayedComponents: .date
                    )
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
                    .zIndex(10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var filterDateSection: some View {
        Section {
            HStack {
                // Default date picker works as expected.
//                DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: [.date]) {
//                    Text("Date").font(.body).foregroundColor(Color.black)
//                }
                
                Text(dateLabelTitle).font(.body).foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    self.showDatePicker = true
                } label: {
                    Text(displayDate).font(.body).foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 28.0)
        } header: {
            Text("Filter")
        }
    }
    
    private var dateRangeSelectionSection: some View {
        Section {
            Picker("Choose date selection range", selection: $selectedPicker) {
                ForEach(segments, id:\.self) { segment in
                    Text(segment).tag(segment).font(.body)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40.0, height: 38.0)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
        } header: {
            Text("Range")
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, button label is showing today's date. But let's say I select March 10 in the date picker and set segmented control to "Week", then button label will be Mar 10, 2024 - Mar 17, 2024. I haven't added that logic yet, but my main issue is when date picker is opened via button click it doesn't lay over the list.

Left image is when date picker is opened via DatePicker(...) directly instead of button click. Right image is after executing my code I shared above.

[image]
[image]

How do I make my code to look like left image? I tried putting opening date picker code in overlay, but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried using `.sheet(isPresented: $showDatePicker) {...}` instead of `.overlay{...}`

Comment: I just tried... it opens a complete new sheet with just date picker in the middle of it.

Comment: Since, `Left image is when date picker is opened via DatePicker(...) directly instead of button click` and you want make your code to look like left image,
 well use the direct method. To customise the displayed date, try this
 SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051670/change-selected-date-format-from-datepicker-swiftui
 
 The post is old, but you could recycle and mordernise the code for your purpose.