# Can I change the date text in a SwiftUI DatePicker?

Tags: ios, swiftui, datepicker

I have a `DatePicker` and I want to change the text that is displayed for the date. So in this example, I want to change '13 Mar 2024' to be 'Today'.

```
        DatePicker(
            "What date?",
            selection: $myDate
        )
```

[image: image saying "What Date?" and then "13 Mar 2024" and then "20:21"]

I know how to change the "What date?" part, but that's not the part that I want to change.

And I know how to use a `DateFormatter()` to generate a `String` from a `Date`, but I can't see how to use a `DateFormatter()` in a `DatePicker`.

Does anyone know how to format the actual date part, without creating a whole new custom `DatePickerStyle` from scratch?

Comment: Not even `UIDatePicker` supports this, so you would have to reinvent a *lot* of things.

Comment: Well … dang. Ok, I’ll do something else instead.

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051670/change-selected-date-format-from-datepicker-swiftui