# calling an API when date changed in DatePicker SwiftUI

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

I saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603932/how-to-detect-a-value-change-of-a-datepicker-using-swiftui-and-combine) but I want a straight callback from Datepicker so I can call a method. In  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603932/how-to-detect-a-value-change-of-a-datepicker-using-swiftui-and-combine) I should add a Slider and in slider's listener call the method.
Is there any better solution to call a method when the DatePicker's date changed?

Comment: You don't need Slider from that example - you may throw it away. You just need to call your API from `updateWeekAndDayFromDate`.

Comment: Oh thank you very much it worked.

Answer (score 6):

how about something simple like this:

```
@State var date = Date()

var body: some View {
        DatePicker(selection: Binding(get: {
            self.date
        }, set: { newVal in
            self.date = newVal
            self.doSomething(with: newVal)
        })) {
            Text("")
        }
}

func doSomething(with: Date) {
    print("-----> in doSomething")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
DatePicker("Date", selection: $date)
        .onChange(of: date) {
            //API goes here
            }
            print($0)
        }
```